# Python library for Telegram APIs

Tags: python, api, automation, chat

I'm looking for a Python 3 library to develop bots for Telegram with the following requirements:

- not abandoned
- up to date
- provided with a good documentation
- as simple as possible
- should support all the Telegram API

What library should I use?

Comment: See section [Using from other programming languages](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/#using-json) of TDLib documentation and [example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/python/tdjson_example.py). Or see [Using TDLib in Python projects](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example#python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/) is very good. It is updated quite often and has:

- has a [complete documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- a sort of [Wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki)
- many [example bots](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/README.md)
- and of course a [Telegram channel](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotchannel).